# NHibernate.Search mapping unknown classes

Tags: nhibernate.search

An assembly contains classes like

```
public class CustomPage : Page, ISearchable
{
    [Searchable]
    public virtual string CustomText { get; set; }
    public virtual string SearchableText { get; set; }
}
```

which I would like to map to Lucene.net. I can't add attributes to those classes and can't use *ISearchMapping* either, because the types are unknown (no reference to that assembly).

How can I do the mappings? All available information is that all types inherit *Page* and implement *ISearchable*. The only property to map is the *SearchableText* (before saving all the properties with *[Searchable]* are concatenated to that property).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this design [Generic DAO Object](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx). I built an entire infrastructure using this implementation. You create an generic DAO and use it with any type of mapped object.

```
public GenericDAO<T>
{
     public List<T> Search(Criteria[] criterias)
     {}

     public T Save(T entity)
     {
     }

     public T Update(T entity)
     {
     }

     Public void Delete(T entity)
     {
     }

}

// any mapped object.
public MyMappedObject
{
   public virtual string ID {get; set;}
   public virtual string Name {get; set;}

   public MyMappedObject()
   {
       ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   }
}

// usage in code.
MyMappedObejct myMappedObjectInstance = new MyMappedObejct();
myMappedObjectInstance.Name = "new name";

GenericDAO<MyMappedObejct> myMappedObejctDao = new GenericDAO<MyMappedObject>();

// Insert
myMappedObjectInstance = myMappedObejctDao.Save(myMappedObjectInstance);

// Select
MyMappedObejct myMappedObjectInstance = myMappedObejctDao.Search().First();

// Update
myMappedObjectInstance.Name = "another name";
myMappedObjectInstance = myMappedObejctDao.Update(myMappedObjectInstance);

// Delete
myMappedObejctDao.Delete(myMappedObjectInstance);
```

This is a very simplified example, I made a much more complex version across more than a hundred classes and it works great.